# Is sensitive data in NextJS .env file safe if it has NEXT_PUBLIC prefix?

Tags: security, next.js, environment-variables, websecurity

Can a malicious actor easily access .env variables in nextJs that have the `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix or as they just as safe as the other .env variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix allows NextJS to send the variable to the client's browser.

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser):

> The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser because of the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix.

Don't use sensitive data with the `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix.